# how do I read grades for knowing where I have to look for watching the ISS?

Tags: artificial-satellite

I want to watch the ISS with naked eye using this tool NASA gives https://spotthestation.nasa.gov/sightings/view.cfm?country=Argentina&region=None&city=Santa_Fe#.WCRzKS3hC1s but I dont know how to read grades in the sense of which direction I have to look to, in order to see the ISS.

Comment: "Grades" - I'm not sure what you mean, but do you mean phrases like "SSW"? If so have a look at [Points of the compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass) and look for the compass point names. You will also need to know which way is North/South at your observing site. (Once seen, the ISS is fairly obvious as a bright, moving, slightly yellow star.)

Comment: probably, it says for example "Appears 10° above SSW" , "Disappears 16° above S"

Comment: Those are angles to indicate the altitude ("height") of the ISS above the horizon. 0° is on the horizon, 90° is the point directly overhead (zenith).  All other values must be in between; the larger the angle, the higher the ISS is above the horizon.

Comment: if you want you can post the comment as answer so I can mark it